# What does it mean for a function f to be C^k "close" to a function g?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

My impression is that $f$ is $C^k$ "close" to $g$ if $f$ is close to $g$, $f'$ is close to $g'$, ... $f^{(k)}$ is close to $g^{(k)}$.

However, my professor is being a bit nebulous on what "close" means. Would anyone be able to explain what it means for a function to be "close" to another? Does it imply some sort of conjugacy?

The context: My professor is attempting to define $C^k$ Structural Stability.

Comment: Means uniform norm on each of the derivatives of $f-g$ up to order $k$ can be made $<\varepsilon$.